# textview centered on rectangle

Tags: android, grid-layout

I want to draw text on a rectangle using xml. I want the text centered on the rectangle. Both the rectangle and text are inside a gridlayout for a reason.

```
<GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/daily"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:rowCount="1" >

        <TextView android:background="@drawable/green_rect_small" />

        <Space android:layout_width="3dp" />

        <RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/green_rect_large" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/daily_readings"
                android:background="@drawable/green_rect_large"
                android:text="@string/daily_readings"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

I can't get it done whether I set the rectangle as the bg of the text view or as a seperate view. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the rectangle as the RelativeLayout background then make the text center on it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/daily"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:rowCount="1" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp" 
            android:background="@drawable/green_rect_large">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/daily_readings"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="daily_readings"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use a RelativeLayout, or a separate View to draw your green rectangle. If I am understanding you correctly you can achieve everything you are wanting with just a single TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="#339933"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

and the result is:

[image]

Comment: I might add an icon later if the customer wants one so I am keeping the relative layout but your way is a more efficient way though.